# AWS ALB rule to point to S3 key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a number of different domain names for various applications, across multiple load balancers, which all need to expose a single "/.well-known/..." verification path.

I'm trying to find a simple generic solution, which will be easy to understand and maintain.

My first attempt was to put the verification file into an S3 bucket, and use a simple redirect rule for the ALB. However it seems the service we're trying to verify does not follow redirects, so that option is out unfortunately.

Another solution would be to use a Lambda Function target group, and have this function return the content from the S3 file. While I'm confident this would work, it's a lot more complicated to setup and I would like to explore simpler solutions first, if there are any.

So just to re-iterate, this needs to work for various ALB's, which point to various types of applications, ECS, EC2 (windows and linux) etc. I want something that's completely seperate from the actual applications.

Comment: ALB supports `fixed-response` action. Is the file big? Maybe you can return it content as fixed response?

Comment: @Marcin Unfortunately it's too large. This was actually what I tried first. The file is 9k.

Comment: In this case, I think lambda is your best choice. You could also host the file on tiny ec2 instance or a ecs container, if you don't want to involve lambda.